# Decoding error in python 3

Tags: python

Trying to decode a picture, having some problems with these very attributes:

```
headerdata = struct.unpack("4s"+\
                               "I"+\
                               str(Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH)+"s",
                                data[:4+4+Header.MAX_FORMAT_LENGTH].encode())
    header.magicnum = headerdata[0]
    header.size = headerdata[1]
    header.fformat = headerdata[2].strip("\x00").decode()
```

I know that something with `encode()` and `decode()` fuctions, but can't figure out how it works with my part.

And having this error:

> header.fformat = headerdata[2].strip("\x00").decode()
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

What am I doing wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `headerdata` contains `bytes`, the argument of `strip` must also be `bytes`:

```
headerdata[2].strip(b"\x00").decode()
```

note that value `0` is a bit special and when decoding the bytes object, it will terminate your string.